# RTAB-Map with odometry and laserscan

Tags: navigation, odometry, kinect, rtabmap, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just getting started with ROS. I've got RTAB-map working with a kinectv2, but I'm seeing loss of tracking when there aren't enough feature points in the camera view.

I was wondering if adding odometry input would alleviate this problem in the actual robot? Would a laser scanner improve accuracy as well?

I'm contemplating buying a laser scanner as per: http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot

but I'm not certain how the laser scan interacts with RTAB-map. It says that the laser scan is used to construct a 2d occupancy grid, but that can already be done without RTAB-map. Is the 2d laser scan data used to improve performance in the 3d SLAM at all?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225391/rtab-map-with-odometry-and-laserscan/) by [Jack000](https://answers.ros.org/users/25782/jack000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2016-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) on 2016-03-18**:
As you said the problem is when there are not enough features on the current image. The odometry info probably improve the perfomance. I don't think that laser scan alleviate that, it is use to get better results on the mapping but not have any influence on the issue that you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

RTAB-Map can use laser scans to refine odometry transformations (e.g., wheel odometry). So yes, if you have a LiDAR, this will improve the map. See [Kinect+Odom+2D laser](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot#Kinect_.2B-_Odometry_.2B-_2D_laser) configuration for example (many RTAB-Map videos used this configuration). Visual odometry is not used in this configuration to avoid the problems you mentioned (the environment has many white walls).

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) on 2016-03-21**:
Thanks for the info and I really like your loop closure method

**Comment by [atomoclast](https://answers.ros.org/users/26451/atomoclast/) on 2016-12-19**:
Can you use RTAB-Map to build a 3D map with Laser/Odom information ONLY? Any tutorial I have seen uses some form of depth image/optical image to build up a pointcloud/point map.

I know that the whole purpose is to use imagery, but I would my current robotic application my not allow for that.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-12-22**:
2D laser scans (LaserScan input) or 3D laser scans (arbitrary PointCloud2 input) can be used to output a 2d occupancy map or a 3d cloud/octomap respectively. A camera is required only for loop closure detection (if you sync fake empty images, you could get what you want but without loop closure).